# Creating indexes on AutoId and time column

Tags: sql-server, performance, index-tuning

My table structure is as follows

```
Events(
  AutoId int identity(1,1) //Primay Key, clustered index
  EventTime   datetime          // non unique, non clustered index
  FileName    nvarchar(1000)
  SystemName  nvarchar(1000)
  other columns
)
```

values in time column is almost increasing

```
Queries:
  List all events for last 7 days, last 1 month
  List all events where order by EventTime and SystemName or FileName like something
```

EventTime is present in most of the queries either through order by or filter clause.

```
Data Variations:
  Events table can have a two or three million rows
  It can have data for past one year
```

Non clusterd index on EventTime column is not always used because it can't filter enough data.

What all options can I try to improve overall query performance?

Comment: Since AutoId and EventTime both columns have auto increasing values can indexe on EventTime share the data pages of cluster index on AutoId. This will avoid the need of lookup in cluster index

Answer (score 3):

For history tables such as this one, it's often appropriate to create the *clustered* index with a date field as the leading column, and have the primary key index nonclustered.

In this case, since you know `EventTime` is non-unique, you can add the `AutoId` column to the key to make it unique (instead of relying on a uniquifier).

This is how the clustered index would be created (after first dropping the existing primary key constraint):

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Events_EventTime_AutoId
    ON [Events](EventTime, AutoId);
```

And then recreate the primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE [Events] WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Events
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(AutoId);
```

This setup allows for efficient date-range-based queries like the examples you've provided, and still doesn't create too much fragmentation to the base table as the clustering key is generally ever-increasing.

Comment: I was also thinking on exactly same lines. But It will increase the size of clustering key, size of non clustered indexes and also Clustered index seek time.

Comment: For me ideal solution will be somehow force SQL server to share the data pages between cluster index created on AutoId column and non clustered index created on eventTime column

Comment: @manish: If you're always doing date-range-based queries, you won't *need* any nonclustered indexes. The increase in key size will be largely irrelevant compared to the data in the table. If you're concerned about seeking on the primary key (why?), yes, it will be slightly slower after this change, but is that really the most expensive part of the workload? For maximum performance, you could create indexes that `INCLUDE` every column in the table, but then you pay the storage penalty. It's always a balance. Your "ideal" doesn't exist in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks again for helping. Any idea on why my "ideal" solution of sharing data pages between cluster and non cluster index is not there? Is any other DBMS provide this?

Comment: In my application Events table can have a few million rows, But most of the time I need to display around 20 to 25 Events(due to paginated UI) based on certain filters(event time will be there almost all the time, other possible filters are FileName, SystemName etc).  So I am thinking of creating of creating non clustered index on EventTime with FileName, SystemName(possible filter candidates) etc as included columns. This index will narrow down the result set to around 25. Then to get the complete row data we will have 25 cluster index seek.

Comment: @manish: Because that's not how it works in SQL Server. I don't know internals for other engines, so I can't help you with that. For the scenarios you mentioned, my solution will work. Is it *the most* efficient? No. Covering nonclustered indexes for each combination will be *the most* efficient. But to do so, you're back to the disk space problem. You will almost always improve performance at a cost to some other resource.